# How to find execution status of a service on Remote computer?

Tags: status, remote-desktop

1. **sc query serviceName** command will give the running status of specified service on local computer.
2. Also **sc \\192.168.100.112 query serviceName** will give the running status of specified service on remote computer whose ip address is 192.168.100.112.
   But when I used **sc \\192.168.100.112 query serviceName**, i am getting something like 
   **[SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 5:

   Access is denied.**

   Can anyone throw some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running this command under a domain admin account? It's a must for this to succeed.. Also notice that in W8K service names are case sensitive.

Comment: How can i run under a domain admin account?

Comment: Close your session an log on to the machine from where you're invoking the command with a domain administrator account. You need the right user name and password.